# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sender' when trying to run Python code from C++

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, linux, ubuntu

it is necessary to run certain Python code while executing C++ code. Python code should send an email with a password generated in C++ code to an email. The problem is that everything is fine when compiling, but when I run it directly, I catch the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sender' (sender is the name of my Python file)

here is my Python code

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

def send_email(recipient_email, passw):
    sender = "sender2023@gmail.com"
    password = "rkmwruhqnsv"

    server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    server.starttls()

    message = "You requested password recovery in our taxi service.\nYour new password: " + passw

    try:
        server.login(sender, password)
        msg = MIMEText(message)
        msg["Subject"] = "Password Recovery"
        server.sendmail(sender, recipient_email, msg.as_string())

        return "The message was sent successfully!"
    except Exception as _ex:
        return f"{_ex}\nCheck your login or password please!"
```

here is my C++ code

```
#include <Python.h>

int main(){
    Py_Initialize();

    PyObject* module = PyImport_ImportModule("sender");
    if (!module){
        PyErr_Print();
        return 1;
    }

    const char* mail = "example@gmail.com";
    const char* password = "zxc4143grl";

    PyObject* function = PyObject_GetAttrString(module, "main");
    if (!function || !PyCallable_Check(function)){
        PyErr_Print();
        return 1;
    }

    PyObject* args = Py_BuildValue("(ss)", mail, password);
    PyObject* return_value = PyObject_CallObject(function, args);
    if (!return_value){
        PyErr_Print();
        return 1;
    }

    Py_DECREF(args);
    Py_DECREF(function);
    Py_DECREF(module);

    Py_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

to compile, I used the command `g++ -I/usr/include/python3.10 run.cpp -o main -lpython3.10`

I was expecting a quiet launch and receiving a test email, but I got an error that I don't know how to handle. I didn't find anything on google

Comment: Is the module `sender` located in python system module path?

Comment: no, it's just a .py file (sender.py ) which is in my project

Comment: You should `PyObject *sys_path = PySys_GetObject("path"); PyList_Append(sys_path, PyString_FromString("base-path-to-sender"));`